# Did Guru Tegh Bahadur really save Hindu religion?

Tags: history, sikhism

I have heard from fellows, who are Hindus, that Guru Teg Bahadur laid his life to save Hindu Religion.

As per Chronicle, Teg Bahadur expect Kashmiri pundits to convert to Sikh Faith I.e to reject all philosophies like Idolatory and other aspects and believe and accept Sikh way of LIFE.

Kashmiri pundits saying to Aurangzeb that you should talk to our Guru(Teacher), if he converted then we will.

Calling teg Guru is acceptance of Sikh philosophy.

How can we say Teg Bahadur saved Hinduism?

Comment: If Guru Teg Bahadur ji was hindu then why hindus do not worship our gurus.... Why they worship only their devi devtas.... Today Hindu religion and our country Bharat exists because of his sacrifice only.. I salute my Guru's sacrifice

Comment: @AgamdeepSingh: Hindus en masse visit gurudwaras and put their mathas to wahe guru, respect and worship the guru grant sahib ji there; eat in langar with everybody there. Have you ever seen one muslims attending in gurudwara, in these modern times(although its muslims own choice and I am fine with that). -- So, does not this prove that even in modern times, Hindus have very much respect and brotherly feeling to sikhs. Just goto any gurudwara in Northern india and count number of khalsa sikh vs hindus visitors there in a day, and you will practically understand this respect.

Comment: No he didn't, Hinduism existed thousands of years before him, and it would continue to exist regardless of whether Guru Bahadur existed.

Answer (score 5):

> As per Chronicle, Teg Bahadur expect Kashmiri pundits to convert to Sikh > Faith I.e to reject all philosophies like Idolatory and other aspects and > believe and accept Sikh way of LIFE.

I have not read that anywhere in 30 years of my life except in propaganda materials.

Guru Teg Bahadur gave his life to defend the right of Kashmiri Pandits to practise their religion in a Muslim empire. If it was Muslims being persecuted in a Hindu Rashtra, he would have done the same. That is the thesis of Sikhism.

His death led to uprise of Sikhs under Guru Gobind Singh, which gave a tough challenge thus slowing down the mass conversions that Aurangzeb was hell bent on.

None of the Guru's expected others to change religion. Infact it is anti-thesis to fundamental of Sikhism. If that was the case, the Bhakats including Namdev and Kabir and sufis like Baba Farid, whose writing are part of Guru Granth Sahib would had been asked to convert before including their writings.

Sikhism neither endorses conversion nor fears it. Till today Darbar Sahib, Amritsar's four doors signify being open to people of four corners of the world without passing judgement on what they believe.

Discourse and discussion though has always been part of Sikhi from the very first Guru who refused to practise Hinduism, wearing Janeo, but did not force others to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Hi.SX. We encourage you to add citation(s) to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Our Hindu Brothers And Sisters Should Know The Facts**

The Mughal Emperor, Aurangzeb cherished the ambition of converting India into a land of Islam. This philosophy was also pleaded by Shaikh Ahmad Sirhindi (1569–1624), leader of the Naqashbandi School, to counter the liberal policies of Akbar's reign.The Emperor's experiment was carried out in Kashmir. The viceroy of Kashmir, Iftikar Khan (1671–1675) carried out the policy vigorously and set about converting non-Muslims by force. A group of Kashmiri Pandits (Kashmiri Hindu Brahmins), approached Guru Tegh Bahadur and asked for help.They, on the advice of the Guru, told the Mughal authorities that they would willingly embrace Islam if Guru Tegh Bahadur, did the same. 
Orders of the arrest of the Guru were issued by Aurangzeb, who was in present day North West Frontier Province of Pakistan subduing Pushtun rebellion. The Guru was arrested at a place called Malikhpur near Anandpur after he had departed from Anandpur for Delhi. Before departing he appointed his son, Gobind Rai (Guru Gobind Singh) as the next Sikh Guru. 
He was arrested, along with some of his followers, Bhai Dayala, Bhai Mati Das and Bhai Sati Das by Nur Muhammad Khan of the Rupnagar police post at the village Malikhpur Rangharan, in Ghanaula Parganah, and sent to Sirhind the following day. The Faujdar (Governor) of Sirhind, Dilawar Khan, ordered him to be detained in Bassi Pathana and reported the news to Delhi. His arrest was made in July 1675 and he was kept in custody for over three months. He was then cast in an iron cage and taken to Delhi in November 1675.The Guru was put in chains and ordered to be tortured until he would accept Islam. When he could not be persuaded to abandon his faith to save himself from persecution, he was asked to perform some miracles to prove his divinity. On his refusal, Guru Tegh Bahadur was beheaded in public at Chandni Chowk on 11 November 1675. Guru Ji is also known as "Hind Di Chadar"

P.S.

P.N.K. Bamzi’s book, A History of Kashmir describes those days:
Iftikhar Khan… …was using force to convert the Pandits in Kashmir to Islam. Some pious men among the Pandits then met and decided to go to Amarnath and invoke the mercy of Lord Siva (at their sacred cave:editor) for deliverance from the tyrannies of the bigot. At the Amarnath cave, one of the pandits saw in a dream Lord Siva, who told him to go to Tegh Bahadur, the Ninth Sikh Guru, in the Punjab and ask for his help to save the Hindu religion. He spoke to his companions about the revelation. About 500 proceeded to Anandpur where Guru Tegh Bahadur was living.

Answer (score 1):

The good thing about Sikh religion is you can practice is without converting to Sikhism.Many of the slokas of famous hinuds and muslims religious leader has been included in guru granth sahib. During the time of guru Tegh bahadur, lot of his disciples were hindus who would listen to this teaching but were never asked to convert to Sikhs. Kashmiri hindus were being forced by the mughal emperor to convert to Islam. This really was bothering kashmiri hindus and they went to Guru Tegh Bahadur for help. Guru Tegh Bahadur agreed to help the hindus and said the solution to this problem is very easy. Upon his advice, group of hindus went to the emperor and said if he could convert one man to Islam, then all the Hindus would agree to accept Islam as their faith. The emperor got very happy with this and asked Guru Tegh bahadur to come to his court. Upon his arrival, emperor asked him to convert to Islam and he will be rewarded with money,palace and many wifes, but guru refused. This really angered emperor and he ordered to kill guru Tegh bahadur.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. You should cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree that Teg bahadur saved Hindus. Hindus are just not handful number of pundits that been saved by Teg Bahadur from been converted to Islam. Hindus and Hinduism is very diverse and wide and Teg bahdur was a hindu himself.